# Die cut for packaging

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-production, dieline

I have to make the design for a box of chocolates for a company. The client gave me the box and said to take the measurements for the design. Am I supposed to make the die cut? I thought it was the printer that had to do it ?

Comment: That will depend. If the client already has a die from previously produced boxes and wants it to be reused, then the printer is likely to be able to provide you with a file for the die. Your best bet is to talk to the printer. They may also have standard templates they will want you to use.

Answer (score 1):

Tear down the box best you can and measure based on the clients old product specs. The printer will not always care. Plus this sounds like you are still in the proofing stages so measure, be prepared and provide them with the design that "presents" the best. Then before pre-press speak to the printer about the die cut and they should be able to provide you with some tips or an exact template. Sometimes an online printer will have specs for normal stuff like folders and basic boxes but not if it's unique.